# NGINX: Completely discard second POST when sent in under 500ms?

Tags: nginx, phpbb3

I would like to completely discard (not buffer, queue or respond to) any POST request from a user within 500ms of the first POST.

I've looked at https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/ but not sure it "fits".

Basically, nginx is sitting in front of phpbb forum software, and it looks like when someone accidentally double-clicks (usually between 100-200ms), then two posts get made, I think because the server takes about 200ms to respond.

phpbb is supposed to have inbuilt "flood control" of 15 seconds, but I guess it can't check the DB before the next request comes in.

So to silently reject the second click would be ideal.